# Parser error: Expected token semicolon got LParen

Tags: contract-deployment

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4 .18;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";


contract MetaCoin {

    struct hospital {
        uint index;
        uint record;
        address patientdata;

        mapping(address => uint) _patientrecord;
        bytes32[] record;



    }
    // mapping the address to the previous report  


    function Metacoin() {

        patient = msg.sender;
        doctor = msg.sender;



    }




    event verify(patientPublicKey, doctorPublicKey, timestamp, uint8 consentCode); // verification process

    function verify(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(bool) {
        return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s, address) == address;



    }

    function isSigned(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns(bool) {
        return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s) == address;

    }

    function Time_call() returns(uint256) {
        return block.number;
    }

    modifier onlypatient() {
        if (msg.sender != patient) throw;
        _;
    }

    modifier onlydoctor() {
        if (msg.sender != doctor) throw;
        _;
    }

    function getAddressfromPublicKey(bytes _publickey) returns(address signer) { // getting address from the public key
        bytes32 keyHash = keccak256(_publickey);
        uint result = 0;
        for (uint i = keyHash.length - 1; i + 1 > 2; i--) {
            uint c = uint(keyHash[i]);
            uint to_inc = c * (16 ** ((keyHash.length - i - 1) * 2));
            result += to_inc;
        }
        result record;
    }
}




contract Signagreement { // signing the agreement by both patient and doctor
    address patient;
    address doctor;

    function patient(address _patient) {
        patient = _patient;
    }

    function doctor(address _doctor) {
        doctor = _doctor;

    }


    modifier onlyPatient() {
        require(msg.sender == patient);
        _;

    }
    modifier onlydoctor() {
        require(msg.sender == doctor);
        _;

    }

    function data() {
        patient = msg.sender;
        doctor = msg.sender;
    }


    struct recordstructs {
        bool approvedBypatient;
        bool approvedBydoctor;

    }
    // this agreement is all publicly explorable
    mapping(bytes32 => recordstruct) public recordstructs;
    bytes32[] public DataList; //all
    bytes32[] public approvedData; //approved

    event LogproposedData(address _patient, bytes32 docHash);
    event ApprovedproposedData(address _doctor, bytes32 docHash);
    // constructor
    function agreement(string timestamp_patient, address _patientdata, string timestamp_doctor) {
        patient = block.timestamp_patient && address_patient && Identification_patient;
        doctor = block.timestamp_doctor && address_doctor && Identification_doctor;
    }


    // for convenient iteration 
    function getDataCount() public constant returns(uint docCount) {
        return DataList.length;

    }

    function getApprovedCount() public constant returns(uint docCount) {
        return DataList.length;
    }



    // approve the agreement
    function agreeDoc(bytes32 Hash) public returns(bool success) {
        if (msg.sender != patient && msg.sender != doctor) throw; //abort the session//unknown person
        if (msg.sender == patient) recordstructs[hash].approvedBypatient = true;
        if (msg.sender == doctor) recordstructs[hash].approvedBypatient = true;
        if (block.number(patient) == block.number(doctor)) recordstructs[hash].approvedBypatient = true; {
            if (msg.sender(patient) == msg.sender(doctor)) recordstructs[hash].approvedBypatient = true;
        }
        if (recordstructs[hash].approvedBypatient == true) {
            uint docCount = DataList.push(hash);
            LogApprovedData(msg.sender, hash);


        } else {
            uint apprCount = approvedData.push(hash);
            LogProposedData(msg.sender, hash);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

// permissions to P2P network
contract permissionsP2P is Enabled {

    struct consentedPatientDataTuple {
        bytes32 verificationmessage;
        address patientdata;


    }

    function records(address _patientdata) {
        records = _patientdata;

    }
    struct consentPatientCode {

        uint8 consentCode;
        // 0 no permission
        // 1 for retrieve the data
        // 2 for add the data
        // 3 for update the data
        // 4 for append the data

    }


    mapping(address => uint8) public permissions;
    mapping(address_patientdata => consentPatientcode) public patientconsent;
    mapping(address_patientdata => consentedPatientDataTuple) public patientdoctorconsent;


    function retrieveData(address _patientdata, uint8 index) returns(bytes32) {

        mapping(uint => address) _patientdata;
        address _patientdata = msg.sender;
        uint retrievedData = address _patientdata && consentpatientCode;
        var cons = consentpatientCode(address _patientdata, consentCode);

        if (consentCode = 1 && msg.sender == doctor || msg.sender == patient) {
            if (DataList[address _patientdata].init == false) {
                return 0;

            } else {
                DataList[address _patientdata].record[index];
                return record(result);

            }
        }

    }

    function addData(address _data, bytes32 record) returns(uint result) {
        var cons = consentpatientCode(address _patientdata, consentCode);

        if (consentCode = 2 && DataList.[address _patientdata].init == false) {
            return 0;
        } else if (data == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            DataList[address _patientdata].record[index].push(record);
            DataList[address _patientdata].responsible.push(resp);
            return 2; // means data added to the patientdatabase

        }
    }

    function confirmData(address _data, bytes32 report) returns(bool) {
        if (address _record != 0x0) {
            // ensure the caller is patient or doctor
            address _doctor = address _data.Identification _doctor;
            address _patient = address _data.Identification _patient;
            if (msg.sender == doctor || msg.sender == patient) {
                if (DataList[address _data].init == false || record == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function updateData(address _patientdata, bytes32 record) returns(bool) {
        var cons = consentpatientCode(address _patientdata, consentCode);

        if (consentCode = 3 && DataList.[address _patientdata].init == false) {

            address_ patientdata.record[index] = record;
        }
    }
}

function appendData(address _patientdata, bytes32 record) returns(bool) {
    var cons = consentpatientCode(address _patientdata, consentCode);

    if (consentCode = 4 && DataList.[address _patientdata].init == false) {

        bytes(record).push(record);
    }

    function set(DataList[address _patientdata], bytes32 record) {
        DataList[address _patientdata].record[index] = record;
    }


}
}
}
```

Comment: your code was not legible. Even formatting it still contains a block that is wrong. The code from `appendData` has a wrong scope. Please try to check your code first and explain what's your issue

Comment: as am trying to modify the code. Can you please explain what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your contract. For example in this snippet

```
event verify(patientPublicKey, doctorPublicKey, timestamp, uint8 consentCode);

function verify(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(bool) {
    return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s, address) == address;
}
```

- An event and a function with the same name
- Event parameters are declared without the type
- The function ecrecover receives 4 parameters and you pass 5 parameters
- You are using address as a variable but it is a type

For small contracts you can use remix.ethereum.org to verify the correct syntax of your contract. It will indicate the line causing the error, and a description of the error.